# Android: Load layout from xml to new layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to load layout dafined in xml to newly created LinearLayout object. Is that possible?

```
LinearLayout new_layout = new LinearLayout(context);
new_layout.load(R.layout.my_layout); // is something like this possible?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is usually done this way

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
LinearLayout newLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
```